# Generate randomly a list of 20 elements (elements should be between -50 and 50)

Tags: python

I need to display the list on the screen. With
use of the list generator generate a new list based on it, in
which double the negative elements. Output a new list to
screen.
The first list outputs normally, without any problems. But I have an error with the displaying of the second list.

```
    import random

c = 0

x = [ (random.randint (-50, 50) ) for c in range (20)]
print ('First list:', x) 

y = [x * 2 (random.randint (-50, 50) ) for c in range (20) if x < 0]
print ('Second list:', y )
```

Comment: What is your output?

Comment: First list: [31, 21, 13, 8, -8, -39, -46, -26, -11, -17, 1, -35, -48, 47, 31, -15, 22, 35, 32, -33]
<>:8: SyntaxWarning: 'int' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
<>:8: SyntaxWarning: 'int' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
<ipython-input-37-f10a6c6814c8>:8: SyntaxWarning: 'int' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
  y = [x * 2 (random.randint (-50, 50) )for c in range (20) if x < 0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an if statement to filter only the negative elements you want to double:

```
from random import randint

x = [randint(-50, 50) for _ in range(20)]
print(f'{x = }')
# If you want to keep only the doubled negative elements
y = [n * 2 for n in x if n < 0]
print(f'{y = }')
# If you want to keep the non negative elements as well you can use an if-else
z = [n * 2 if n < 0 else n for n in x]
print(f'{z = }')
```

**Example Output:**

```
x = [-2, -31, 35, -3, -34, 47, 28, 34, -18, 26, -25, -48, 18, -30, 1, 48, 43, -29, -30, -22]
y = [-4, -62, -6, -68, -36, -50, -96, -60, -58, -60, -44]
z = [-4, -62, 35, -6, -68, 47, 28, 34, -36, 26, -50, -96, 18, -60, 1, 48, 43, -58, -60, -44]
```

Comment: I need the second list to display only doubled negative elements. I'm new to this language, so please excuse my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

```
y = [x * 2 (random.randint (-50, 50) ) for c in range (20) if x < 0]
```

The error is in this part of your code:

```
[x * 2 (random.randint (-50, 50) ) ...
```

You have an unmatched `)` too.

---

Maybe you meant something like this?

```
y = [c * 2 for c in range(20)]
z = [random.randint(-50, 50) * c for c in y]
```

---

If you want to filter the `double` and `negative` elements, you can do something like this:

```
z = [element for element in y if (element < 0 and isinstance(element, float)]
```